# Is there a way to replace all unwanted numbers and characters with regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

Our site has a phone number in two different inputs, in first one you should be able to write only p*refix(like 6151 etc.)* and in second one you should write other *numbers(like 8844 057 etc.)*. Problem comes, since this approach isn't really user friendly, when customer writes their phone numbers they either write the whole number in first *field(like 6151 8844 075)* and/or add +49 prefix for country which is not needed.

I've tried changing regex for **!preg_match** from `"@^[0-9 ]+$@" to "(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){3,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))"`, it works but partially, not really solution for my problem. Tried including little info boxes underneath the input but that didn't work either*(11% customers still wrote wrong phone number)*

```php
if (
        (
            $_POST[konto] != "" &&
            !preg_match("(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){3,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))", $_POST[konto])
        )
        ||
        (
            $_POST[konto] != "" &&
            !preg_match("(\(?([\d \-\)\–\+\/\(]+){6,}\)?([ .\-–\/]?)([\d]+))", $_POST[konto])
        )
    )
```

```html
<div class="">
            <p></p>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="">
                </label>

                <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" name="" value="">
                        <input class="form-control rwd-text" id="" type="text" name="" value="" />
                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                            <input class="form-control rwd-text" id="" type="text" name="" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center h3 margin-top-0">/</div>

                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <input class="form-control rwd-text" id="" type="text" name="" value="" />
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-15">
                        <div class="control-label"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way with !preg_match, **FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT** or someother function to strip the phone number from **+49-6151/8844-057** to only **6151 8844 057(so no invalid characters)** and that for the first input it only sends first **prefix(6151 without +49 or 0049 or any other country prefix)** and for second input to send only the number. I literally don't have any clue how to make this happen. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a technical reason, like automatic grouping according to Vorwahl, you need to split the phone number? If there isn't I *always* would recommend not using splits like this at all.

Comment: Yeah, there is, it should be saved in database and other workers should have access to them, but since it's not typed correctly, other workers don't have access to them. I know using splits is not recommended, but the code was already there when I've started working here, and my boss doesn't want to change much.

Comment: You do not necessarily need make use of a regular expression as this might over complicate the code you are trying to make to reach your goal. You could try to write your own code to do something similar.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that this "works" and is live, if I change the code and it doesn't work and push it live that would be a big loss for us. I was thinking maybe firstly (after !preg_match) adding FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT to clear everything from any invalid characters and then adding another condition to also clear everything from +/- and any country prefix (since that is allowed with FILTER function), but I'm not too sure that that would fix my problem and also I don't know how to remove country prefix if entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please beware

This code relies heavily on a strict input format. Prefixes like `++496151` won't work. You should search for odd formats in the database and correct those before running this code!

---

Something like this? This is JavaScript code, but it will be translatable into php

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()

const input = [
  {
    prefix: "+49-6151", 
    number: "8844-057",
  },
  {
    prefix: "0049-6151", 
    number: "8844-057",
  },
  {
    prefix: "++49 06151", 
    number: "8844-057",
  },
]

function fixPrefix(prefix) {
  prefix = prefix
    // remove leading '+', '++', and '00' and following digits
    .replace(/^(\+{1,2}|00)\d+/, '')
    // split at none digits
    .split(/\D/)
    // remove empty elements
    .filter(i=>i)
    // rejoin
    .join()
    // add one lleading zero if none is present
    .replace(/^(?!0)/, 0)
  return prefix
}

function fixNumber(number) {
  number = number
    // split at any none digit
    .split(/\D/)
    // remove empty elements
    .filter(i=>i)
    // rejoin with space in between
    .join(" ")
  return number
}

let output = input.map(i => {
 return {
   prefix: fixPrefix(i.prefix),
   number: fixNumber(i.number),
 } 
})

console.info('Input')
console.log(input)
console.info('Output')
console.log(output)
```

The PHP code is like this (See it in action on 3v4l.org here: https://3v4l.org/uRM6S)

```
<?php

$input = [
    [
        "prefix" => "+49-6151", 
        "number" => "8844-057",
    ],
    [
        "prefix" => "0049-6151", 
        "number" => "8844-057",
    ],
    [
        "prefix" => "++49 06151", 
        "number" => "8844-057",
    ],
];



function fixPrefix($prefix) {
    $prefix = preg_replace("/^(\+{1,2}|00)\d+/", '', $prefix);
    $prefix = preg_split("/\D/", $prefix);
    $prefix = array_filter($prefix, function($i) {return !!$i;});
    $prefix = implode($prefix);
    $prefix = preg_replace("/^(?!0)/", "0", $prefix);

    return $prefix;
}

function fixNumber($number) {
    $number = preg_split("/\D/", $number);
    $number = array_filter($number, function($i) {return !!$i;});
    $number = implode($number, " ");
    return $number;
}

$output = array_map(
    function($i) {
    return [
        "prefix" => fixPrefix($i["prefix"]),
        "number" => fixNumber($i["number"]),
    ];
}, $input);

print_r("Input\n");
print_r($input);
print_r("Output\n");
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Something exactly like that. If its not a problem for you, can you please explain the RegEx you've used?

Comment: @asobak I've added PHP code and annotations to JS code

Comment: I have to ask, now if someone wrote his full number like +49-6151/8844-057 in only prefix input field, that would probably return an error?

Comment: That's where your problems start. How can you be sure that there is always a slash (`/`) as separator between prefix and local number? Some might input `++49 (0)6151 88 44-057`. That's the issue with data like these. You'd have to assure that any number is valid by checking against a list of actual country codes, etc. With user generated content you cannot be sure about the format.

Comment: Yeah, I've got your point. So, basically with preg_replace, split and match I can't accomplish that, only if I've been given magically a database full of formats for every country..